# Adjust Div height according to TD height

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `<td>`s in a table and each `<td>` has a 1 pixel border. All divs have the text "My Division".

Now when I add some more text in one of the `<td>`s of them then the height of `<td>` increases and height of `<div>` in that `<td>` also increases but other 3 `<div>` in other 3 `<td>` don't. How to adjust their height also according to the increased `<td>`.

```
<table>
 <tr> 
   <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td> 
   <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td> 
   <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td> 
   <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td> 
 <tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: <table>
   <tr>
     <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td>
  <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td>
  <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td>
  <td height="50"><div style="border:1px solid;">My Division</div></td>
<tr>
</table>

add some other text in first div then the height of td and div will increase but the height of other 3 divs remains constant

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS it will only be possible if your tds have a height given. Then you can make the divs height 100%. But that is not what you are looking for.

To solve your problem you need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
#myTable td { 
  vertical-align:top; 
}

#myTable td div {
  height:100%;   
}
​
```

[jsFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/Njmw6/)